# Purpose of Talend MDM Server

Tags: talend

I need to be able to do the following using Talend Open Studio:

- Standardization and cleansing of source data.
- Deduplication of records.
- Perform Match and Merge operations.
- Versioning control of data (I know this can be done using SCD components).

Is it possible to do all these functions using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration or do I need to use Talend MDM Server?

Answer (score 2):

As a data integration platform, Talend Open Studio, allows to do all these operations :

- Standardization : define your standard schema, map your data with these standardize schema
- cleansing of source data : auditing your database with Talend Data Quality can be interesting before cleansing your data. When you detected some wrong records, you can then proceed to data cleansing with Talend Open Studio components.
- Deduplication of records : combining the tmap, tUniqRow and tAggregateRow can solve duplicated data.
- Match : the tMap join model allows to match data between 2 data sources, with different join model (Inner / Outer join). You can also fuzzy matching techniques to map your data.
- Merge : tAggregateRow allows to merge data for a defined key column.

Depending of your requirements on "versioning control of data", SCD components could do the job.

Talend MDM server can be used when you need to create a repository to put your reference data, and make them available (through web services for example) all over your information system.